# Desired file seemingly not included in upload of Presage?

Tags: cygwin, tar

I am seeking to use Presage and have been following the instructions in the `Read Me file`, found at https://sourceforge.net/p/presage/presage/ci/master/tree/

First, I installed Presage following the setup file under Downloads.  Then, as a Windows user, I downloaded the Cygwin environment.  When I go to unpack Presage, using the code given in the Presage Read Me guide, in the Cygwin command prompt, I receive this output:

```
tar (child): presage-*tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Running the most recent installer for Presage created a new document folder called Presage within my user folder.  I tried copying both the file itself, and then the entire folder, to Downloads, but this did not resolve anything.  Similarly, I tried moving Cygwin to Downloads, but this did not help.  I then conducted a search for `presage.tar.gz`, which is what I want to untar.  The Presage installer provided files `presage_theme.tar.gz` and `presage_files.tar.gz`, but no `presage.tar.gz`.

I then tried the second most recent release of Presage, but this did not fix the problem, either.

What is happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you installed tar?

Comment: I am currently looking through the package manager.  How can I ensure that it is installed?  When I click on it (it is listed under Full or Fully Installed), it revolves between various codes: Keep, Reinstall, Uninstall, 128-1...Which one enables it?

Comment: At what level did you ran the   `tar jxvf presage-*.tar.bz2`

or
`tar zxvf presage-*.tar.gz`

Comment: @roxelana: invoke the cygwin setup utility and look under the "Base" category; you should see "tar" listed as "Keep".  This means that you should have installed tar as part of the base Cygwin installation.  (In other words, you *should* have tar installed unless you have specifically uninstalled it.)  Still, verify tar actually *is* installed, then we can try to figure out what may have gone wrong in your case,

Comment: @varro: Thanks for your response.  Tar is listed as "keep" and, for all I can tell, is installed.  It gives the "help" output when I try "tar --help."

Comment: @antzshrek: I opened the Cygwin terminal and ran the commands (tried both of them, to no avail) right away.  I believe this is what you are asking?  (I am completely self-taught and still learning some terminology.)

Comment: @roxelana under **Downloads**, do you have the **Presage** with a `.tar.gz` extension?

Comment: @antzshrek I have the file, but it is under the Presage folder that was created during installation.  Could this be the root of the problem?

Comment: @roxelana try the solution and let me know how far

Comment: @antzshrek Hmmm.  I tried copying the Presage file into Downloads, and then the whole folder into Downloads, but neither of them produced any difference in the output.  Thoughts?

Comment: @roxelana can you update your question with the structure of your files and directories?

Comment: @antzshrek Good recommendation, I have updated my question.  After looking further, I realized that I have files named presage_theme.tar.gz and presage_files.tar.gz, but no presage.tar.gz.  Any idea why the installation would not have included this crucial element?

Comment: @roxelana I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Download** directory, where **Presage.tar.gz** is located, open your Cygwin terminal, then follow the instructions as also provided in [Presage](https://sourceforge.net/p/presage/presage/ci/master/tree/):

***NOTE**: This will extract the file to the current (**Download**) directory.*

#### STEP 1: Unpacking Presage

On **Linux/Unix**, uncompress and untar the distribution with:

```
tar zxvf presage_theme.tar.gz && tar zxvf presage_files.tar.gz
```

or

```
tar -xzvf presage_theme.tar.gz && tar -xzvf presage_files.tar.gz
```

(This should uncompress 2 different directories for you *presage_theme* and *presage_files*)

#### STEP 2: Configuring Presage

Configuring Presage to different platforms, environments and
operating systems is simply a matter of running

```
./configure
```

in the top-level directory of the distribution. This will configure
Presage for your system. Should you require additional options, try

```
./configure --help
```

to see the available options.

#### STEP 3: Compiling Presage

Kick off the compilation with

```
make
```

This will build the Presage system, libraries and available
plugins.

#### STEP 4: Installing Presage

Install Presage and its support libraries and plugins by typing

```
make install
```

Comment: Hi, thank you!  Unfortunately, this returns the same problem, even though I can see these files in Downloads->Presage:
`tar (child): presage_theme.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: The problem was that my version of Windows was not compatible with even the most recent version of Presage.  There is a patch fix available for it online.